# Cinemachine 2D Camera: Move up and Vertical

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Cinemachine Virtual Camera, and I want it to move only along the Y axis up. How can I achieve this?

I have another question: how can I block the movement along the X axis?
I made the dead zone to 1, but I see a little jerking  when my object moves from the left border of the screen to the right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create vcam extension this template work fine.
This is taken from this forum.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/lock-an-axis-in-2d-vcam-follow-mode.516370/

```
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

/// <summary>
/// An add-on module for Cinemachine Virtual Camera that locks the camera's Z co- 
ordinate
/// </summary>
[ExecuteInEditMode] [SaveDuringPlay] [AddComponentMenu("")] // Hide in menu
public class LockCameraZ : CinemachineExtension
{
[Tooltip("Lock the camera's Z position to this value")]
public float m_ZPosition = 10;

protected override void PostPipelineStageCallback(
    CinemachineVirtualCameraBase vcam,
    CinemachineCore.Stage stage, ref CameraState state, float deltaTime)
{
    if (enabled && stage == CinemachineCore.Stage.Body)
    {
        var pos = state.RawPosition;
        pos.z = m_ZPosition;
        state.RawPosition = pos;
    }
}
}
```

so an extension is better than override main camera position, because you can enable or disable the extension, also you can combine with with another extensions.

Comment: How are extensions enabled and disabled? Sounds magical. Wonderful. Joyous!

Comment: Class CinemachineExtension are classes derivered from Monobehaviour, so they work like a GameComponent. You can enable or disable by using the editor or in script like GetComponent<LockCameraZ>().enable = true or false